# How to use ToListAsync() in .net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core

First of all I am beginner, using asp.net core web API (3.1), so my question is in the below code why not able to call the `toListAync` method.
While calling `toListAsync` method getting error. Can anyone suggest some tips to solve the problem. I was trying to call the method as an async with dapper.

> Error:- `Task<IEnumerable<Owner>>` does not contain a definition for `toListAsync` and no accessible extension method `toListAsync` accepting a first argument of type `Task<IEnumerable<Owner>>` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<Owner>> GetCustomerAsync()
        {
            IAsyncEnumerable<Owner> owners = null;
            var query = "select * from tbl_Owner";
            using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection())
            {
             var  k =  await sqlCon.QueryAsync<Owner>(query).toListAsync();
                return owners;
            }                
        }
```

Comment: Typo error: [owners =  await sqlCon.QueryAsync<Owner>(query).ToListAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)  but not `toListAsync()`

Comment: @salahuddin, sorry but in programming I have use ToListAsync but while writing in stackover flow mistakenly I have write toListAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to import the corresponding package？

Try to add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

For EF Core ,you can add the following assembly reference:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: Am using ado.net with dapper not EF core